# Android setBackground(Drawable) consumes too much time

Tags: android, caching, view, bitmap, drawable

I have a tablelayout for a calendar with 300 cells. When the user touches dates in a flow/move touch e.x. 6 days, it sets a background drawable.

The drawable is set with XML (shape, rect, ...). It iterates only over this 6 days, not over all cells.

The Problem is, that on Nexus 7 and older devices setting a backgroundDrawable consumes too much time. When the finger is on the 6th day, it sets the 4th day till it also arrives the last day!!!

How can I improve it ?

Flow: onDown(...), onMove(...) over 6 days, onUp(...).

EDIT:

```
    public boolean onMove(MotionEvent e) {

    Day selectedDay = searchForSelectedDay((int) e.getX(), (int) (e.getY() + getScrollY()));

    if (selectedDay != null && selectedDay != mPreviousDay){
     defineDayContent(mPreviousDay, selectedDay);
    } 

    ...

    defineDayContent(Day arg0, Day arg1){
     //iterates from arg0 till arg1 and sets the background
    for(Day d : (iterate from arg0 till arg1)){             
d.setBackground(Calendar.BACKGROUND_DRAWABLE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is that iteration you meant good for?

Comment: If you onDown ur finger on the first day and move it to the 6th cell (as sample), every time ur finger changes the day, its cells background is set by setBackground(Drawable). That what I meant with iteration, basicly there is no real iteration.

Comment: I think the problem is, to draw a background on a view, the system goes very deep and layouts everytime new.

Answer (score 0):

You provided no code, that's why it's difficult to say where exactly the bottleneck is. I would try following measures.

As the first measure I would preload drawables making sure I don't call `getDrawable()` or `setBackgroundResource()` inside `onTouch()` method.

Secondly, I will make sure I don't call `setBackground()` in `onTouch()` for a view twice or multiple time, if background has already been set.

If first two don't help, I would call `setBackground()` delayed, only after a user slows his/her finger down over a certain view. This will avoid visual effect you described and speed up updates.

Comment: I already did the first two steps. Only on "day-changes" I setBackgrounds. The drawables are set before, so there are no creations of drawable objects, hmmm really difficult.

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing source.

Answer (score 0):

This was not solved, but ...

We tried to inflate views and set visibility of imageviews. Very quick, but the inflating of xmls for 300 cells was to heavy... 2-3 seconds to init.

We just decided to draw the content of the cells. That is very fast in layouting + in performance.

Solution at the end: CustomView + onDraw

yayyy